# Point non-www domain with CNAME Record

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, dns

I am using Heroku for my webapp. After adding a domain, Heroku provides with a url to be pointed to from the domain which looks something like this `xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx.herokudns.com`.

Now this has to be added to my DNS management console as Alias A record or CNAME record. I have options to use either AWS Route53 or Godaddy DNS manager for this. For domain with www.myapp.com, I am able to do this.

But for the domain without www, on AWS Route53, AWS doesn't allow CNAME record to be added for Apex domain (domain without www) in the zone. While trying to do the same as Alias for the A record, it shows error that the value is invalid as the value is not from any of the AWS Services.

On doing the same with GoDaddy, it's not allowing the value '@' in the host field for a CNAME record. And there's no option to add alias of A record.

What are my options here?

Comment: "AWS doesn't allow CNAME record to be added for Apex domain" Noone allows that since it is against the DNS specifications. Various providers offer workarounds often called ALIAS or ANAME.

Comment: Yes, but even for ALIAS, AWS doesn't allow an external URL to be used. It's giving options for the cloud front urls etc hosted on the same account, but not allowing url provided by heroku to be added there.

Comment: The DNS does not deal with URLs for what you attempt to do, but with hostnames and IP addresses. Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, you can instead look at [su] or [sf] but read their help section, and also ask directly your providers for help. Alternatively, there are many many questions already on Heroku, AWS, GoDaddy, etc.

Comment: Hey, what about redirections, try to redirect the base domain name to the www url

Comment: @LuigiLopez In that case, I can not install an SSL unless I have bought SSL from the same provider. Otherwise https://myapp.com will always show security error.

Comment: @Sourabh Just generate a SSL with letsencrypt for www and base domain and that's it.